# retain only 1 item in a list per unique prefix

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have an example situation where I have a list as follows:

```
test = ['a-nyc','a-chi','b-sf','c-dal','a-phx','c-la']
```

the items in this list are naturally ordered in some way, and the objective is to keep the first encountered value for each prefix, e.g. the desired result is a list as follows:

```
['a-nyc', 'b-sf', 'c-dal']
```

is there a handy way of doing this?

looks like this can be done this way:

```
newl = []
prel = []
for i in range(len(test)):
    if test[i].split('-')[0] not in prel:
        newl.append(test[i])
    else:
        pass
    prel.append(test[i].split('-')[0])
```

but not sure if there is a more pythonic solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can try like following also:

```
    test = ['a-nyc','a-chi','b-sf','c-dal','a-phx','c-la']
    prefix = []
    newlist = []
    for i in test:
        if i.split('-')[0] not in prefix:
            prefix.append(i.split('-')[0])
            newlist.append(i)
    print(newlist)
```

In this, if any query then let me know.
Thank you.